# Proving the differentiability of a function in chunks

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

> Let $$f(x) =\begin{cases} x^2 &\text{if }x \text{ is rational}\\0&\text{if }x \text{ is irrational}\end{cases}$$
> Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and find $f'(0)$.

I tried finding the derivatives by definition at the point $x=0$, for $f(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=0$, they both give me they're equal to $0$.

So does that mean $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and that $f'(0)=0$?

Comment: Well, no.  Take the function which is $1$ on the rationals and $0$ on the irrationals.  If you consider $f(x)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ both have derivative $0$ at $x=0$, but the function itself isn't even continuous at $0$ (or anywhere else).

Comment: So how can i prove that f is differantiable at x=0 and find f'(0)?

Comment: Go back to the definition of the derivative.  Prove that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(h)-f(0)}h=0$.

Comment: @MarioM21 You need to compute the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$

Comment: Yes, i computed the limits, one for f(x)= x^2 and one for f(x)=0, they both gave me 0, is this right? Or should i only compute one limit?

Comment: I get so confused when dealing with function in chunks, i got limx->0 f(x)-f(0)/x = limx->0 x^2-x^2/x = 0/x = 0. And limx->0 0-x^2/x = limx->0 -x^2/x = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat tacky to highjack comments from analysis.  However, OP's post query
comment indicates work.

To prove: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = 0.$

For $x \neq 0$ 
$\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = ~
x : x$ rational, $0$ : $x$ irrational.

Thus, for $x \neq 0, |\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}| \leq |x|.$

For $\epsilon > 0,$ choose $\delta = \epsilon.$

Then, $0 < |x| < \delta = \epsilon ~\Rightarrow~ |\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}| < \epsilon. $

Comment: Thanks a lot, your proof is very good and complex/advanced (at least for me).

Comment: But i was looking for like a less rigorous proof, like just using the definition of derivative to compute the limits of both x^2 and 0, both give you they're equal to 0, but i don't know if that's enough to prove that f is differentiable at x=0

Comment: @MarioM21 This problem had two points: (1) be careful indicating that you are only considering $x$ close to $0$, but never $= 0.$ (2) That in a neighborhood around $0$ $f(x)$ will be **incessantly oscillating** between $0$ and $x^2$ depending on whether the value of $x$ being examined in this neighborhood is rational or irrational.  The problem **demands** that you **accommodate** this oscillation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand, but why demands and accommodate are in black, how do you accomodate? or why do you accomodate?

Comment: I had to consider that in a neighborhood around $0$, where $x \neq 0,~ \frac{f(x)}{x}$ was going to be $x$ or $0$, depending on whether $x$ rational or irrational.  I had to demonstrate that this meant that the fraction was **always** $\leq x$.  I then had to demonstrate, that if I made the neighborhood around $0$ *small enough* I (in effect) would have the **luxury of not caring** whether $x$ was rational or irrational.  This way I could *ignore* that there are both rational and irrational #'s arbitrarily close to 0.